# apt-get does not work without an internet connection. How can work around this?

Tags: apt, firewall

I have a host which is firewalled to the point where apt-get is unable to download packages.  That host does not have access to a proxy.

I know in gentoo I could work around the problem by fetching the necessary files using a second host and placing the files in /usr/portage/distfiles .

Does Ubuntu have a similar place I can stash the files to work around the lack of internet access?

Comment: do you want to know how to make local repository

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the answer linked by terdon I was able to derive the following procedure.

Use the second host to fetch the .deb files that the first host was unable to download.

Copy those .deb files to the firewalled host.  Then

```
dpkg -i *whatever*.deb
```

Boom, I now have the software I need.

I'm not sure what I'm missing out on by skipping all the apt-offline gymnastics.

Answer (score 3):

One way of doing this is using `apt-offline`. You can download the package [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/apt-offline) (make sure you also get the dependencies) and install with

```
sudo dpkg -i apt-offline_1.3.1_all.deb
```

Once you have it installed run

```
sudo apt-offline set mypackages.sig --install-packages your_packages (you can also use `--upgrade` for a full upgrade, see `man apt-offline` for more details).
```

Then, take the file that was just generated (`mypackages.sig`), and run

```
sudo apt-offline get mypackages.sig --no-checksum --bundle mypackages.zip
```

Now, go back to your firewalled system to install it:

```
unzip  mypackages.zip
```

That should result in a list of `.deb` files that you can then install manually with `dpkg -i *.deb`.

I also found something called [keryx](https://launchpad.net/keryx) which might be worth checking out:

> Keryx is a free, open source application for updating Linux. The Keryx Project started as a way for users with dialup, or low-bandwidth internet to be able to download and update packages on their debian based distribution of linux. Mainly built for Ubuntu, Keryx allows users to select packages to install, check for updates, and download these packages onto a USB portable storage device. The packages are saved onto the device and are then taken back to the Linux box that it originated from and are then installed.

Finally, you can also do all this manually with `apt-get` from the other system:

```
sudo apt-get update --print-uris -y | sed "s/'//g" | cut -d ' ' -f 1,2 | 
  while read url target; do wget $url -O ./$target; done
```

The command above will download all `.deb` files needed to install your packages. See my answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/104575/22222) for more details on how that works.

#### References

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware#Installing_packages_without_an_Internet_connection
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1637309&p=10198406#post10198406

Comment: @Aditya thanks, I copied most of that from my answer [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/104575/22222) which was using it as an example. Fixed now.

Comment: @Aditya nope, wrong answer, I copied from [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/112358/22222). Note that both answers were mine, no plagiarism involved! :P

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Cube](https://launchpad.net/camicricube)

> **Cube (2013)** is a portable package manager (Like Synaptic and Ubuntu Software Center) that can be used and run in any platform (Windows, Apt-Based Linux Distributions), online and offline, in flashdrive or any removable devices. It enables you to download Linux Applications in any computer, and installs it back to your original computer. It is developed in hope that it become useful to offline Linux users community and to make Linux applications easier to download and install.

You can check also the step by step guide of it [here](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1583)